# How to make a horizontal bar chart using gradient color in android

Tags: android, graph, bar-chart, android-graphview

I've attached a screenshot. As per the screenshot I want to make the horizontal bar chart graph to my activity same as the snapshot. I've done half of it's contents using MP Chart Library. I can't add the x axis values starting from 3 to 9. Also not unable to add the vertical grids.

[image]

Please suggest me what I should do?

In advance thanks for your help and your little help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use GraphView
http://www.android-graphview.org/
I hope it would be helpful.

Comment: does not have horizontal bars. but vertical bars can have a value-depending background color

Comment: @jjoe64 can we set gradient colors for each bar in bar graph ?

Comment: no, for this you have to change somewhere here in the code: https://github.com/jjoe64/GraphView/blob/master/src/main/java/com/jjoe64/graphview/series/BarGraphSeries.java#L227

Answer (score 1):

Create a xml file for a gradient in the /drawable folder and apply it to a LinearLayout as the background. The angle has to be 0.

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <gradient
        android:startColor="#000000"
        android:endColor="#ff3399"
        android:angle="0"/>
</shape>


<LinearLayout 
    android:id="@+id/bar_1" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:background="@drawable/my_gradient"> 
</LinearLayout>
```

Regarding the background: Try the `GridLayout` which enables to 'aggregate' cells. But this might be tricky.

Comment: I'll try to do this but my main focus on the graph in which I can't add the values which is shown into the image.

Comment: If you're ok with a out-of-the-box solution --> https://code.google.com/p/achartengine/ :)